# Scroll customization or use q-scroll-area

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

Main layout:

```
<template>
  <q-layout view="hHh Lpr lfr">
    <q-header>
      <q-toolbar>       
      </q-toolbar>
    </q-header>

    <q-drawer>
    </q-drawer>

    <q-page-container>
      <router-view />
    </q-page-container>

  </q-layout>
</template>
```

Page:

```
<template>
  <q-page>
    <div class="row">...</div>
    </div>
  </q-page>
</template>
```

There is a loop in the class name "row" and I am showing a photo with q-img. The browser automatically scrolls when the photos do not fit on the page. but the scroll sizes and images are not the same in every browser. so I need to customize the scroll.. I used q-scroll-area. but nested scroll appears.. Both the q-scroll area is visible and the browser automatically shows the scroll. how can I fix this? Where should I use q-scroll-area?